# securing self hosted wcf without certificate

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service hosted in a windows service(c#).
Actually, there is only one client application(c#) and multiple services, they are running in several machines and my client request actions to be executed on machines (something like that)
This services are running on machines I dont have access to install certificates so the idea to register a port+certificate is not possible, also, i would need i think one certificate by machine which is also not possible at all.

My question, 
I want to secure communication between my wcf services and client application.
I'm sending sensitive information so I need encryption.

How can I do that without certificate involved ??

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you think of API key authentication for your security? It is something very useful in your situation I think.

Comment: Do API key wuthentication ensure encryption in data exchange ?? Also i'm in .NET 3.5, not 4. it is also available ? Thnks

Comment: I'm not sure if it is available in .NET 3.5. And no it's not encrypted but it contains already some security.

Comment: Autorization is different from encryption. There are many security options in wcf that allow you to autorize some users and/or encrypt messages. You can easily encrypt messages using https but everyone will be able to call your service.

Comment: Well, I give more information that may help to find a solution. I can provide some certificate information from client side because is only one machine, easy to setup, and in wcf service side validate this certificate to recognize authorized client ?? Still encryption is not clear for me. Thks